# How can I write to my lowdb-Database from the frontend, using next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, next.js, web-applications

I am a hobby programmer with some experience in React, primarily using Firebase for my backend. Recently, I have started using Next.js and am wondering if I can use it as a small JSON-based database for local applications on my Raspberry Pi. I have set up LowDB and can access it from server-side rendered components, but I am unsure of the best way to make them accessible from interactive frontend components, such as allowing user input and saving it to the database. I have considered using Next.js's own API endpoint, but I am unsure if this is the most efficient and desired method. It feels strange to use a DB query in server-side components but an API for data changes.

Answer (score 0):

NextJs as great framework derived from React, its more for UI frontend, for interacting with DB normally you would use an NodeJS API framework like NestJs or simply Express with some kickstart templates.
You will not like use SSC since its just not the way/goal it was designed. like dentist doctor doing eye check haha

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I had hoped to be able to do away with separation by using Next.js. My plan was to use it to serve my entire frontend and also to easily save a few small inputs in a file, without having to set up something like Express separately.

Comment: If so and you are great learner, you can use api route from nextjs, its a new feature i would warn you might encounter issues that not well known, so definately possible but you might put your self into a hard place instead of using well known community mature solutiosn, anyway, up to you my friend!